# Algebra in congruence class

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $l\geq1$, it is known that if $a\equiv b\text{(mod }p^l)$, where $p$ is prime, then $a^p\equiv b^p\text{(mod }p^{l+1})$. I'm trying to prove that if $p$ is an odd prime and $l\geq2$, then $(1+ap)^{p^{l-2}}\equiv1+ap^{l-1}\text{(mod }p^{l+1})$. I'm fine with the proof, but there is one algebraic step that I don't know how to justify:

$(1+ap)^{p^{l-1}}\equiv(1+ap^{l-1})^p\text{(mod }p^{l+1})$.

I really am not sure what to do here. I expand $[(1+ap)^{p^{l-2}}]^p=(1+ap)^{p^{l-1}}$, but I don't know where to take it to achieve $(1+ap^{l-1})^p\text{(mod }p^{l+1})$.

What should I do?

Comment: Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+ap)^{p^{l-1}}$

Comment: Of course. *facepalm*